# An Appscript function is not getting called in an API Executable app

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension

Trying to make an API executable app

```
post({  'url': 'https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/'+SCRIPT_ID+':run',
                'callback': callbackfunction,
                'token': token,
                'request': {'function': 'getData'},
            });

function post(options) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                options.callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
                sampleSupport.log('post', xhr.readyState, xhr.status, xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.open('POST', options.url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + options.token);
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(options.request));
    }
```

This method gives an error:-
**@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError"
errorMessage: "Script function not found: getData"
errorType: "ScriptError"**

Appscript function

```
var calendarId = "xyz";
function getData() {
   try {
  var new=new Date();
  var events = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, {
    timeMin: start.toISOString(),    
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
    maxResults: 10
  });
  if (events.items && events.items.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.items.length; i++) {
      var event = events.items[i];
      if (event.start.date) {
        // All-day event.
        var start = new Date(event.start.date);
   //     Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, start.toLocaleDateString());
      } else {
        var start = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
       
      }

    }
     Logger.log(event);
      return {"status":"ok", 'cal':event};
  } else {
    Logger.log('No events found.');
  }
  } catch(e){
    // if error return this
    Logger.log(e);
    return {"status": JSON.stringify(e)};
  }
}
```

Any ideas what is the mistake?

Comment: Hi there @Piya! I don't understand how you are trying to run this script, are you using the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute)? Also this issue may have originated in the function scope, so to check that please share the full script structure. Feel free to anonymize the private data on it.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-Guzel Heron  , yes I have created a project in google console and added App Scipt API as a scope and also created client ID's for it .This is the only method " function getData() " that is present in App script and its running perfect in the app script editor , but while  running it through  javascript " script : run " its not getting called.

Comment: This error message may originate in a stale token. Could you please generate a new fresh token and see if it helps? To prevent a faulty script, could you try to run a simple example function from the Apps Script API? Please share your findings.